# Quitar carácter especiales en líneas concretas con sed

Tags: regex, sed

Tengo un script de configuración de bind 9 con Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS en el que quiero eliminar el carácter `//` que comenta las líneas 13 y 15 del fichero `named.conf.options`. No termino de entender cómo puedo hacerlo con sed.

El fichero está escrito así:

```
// forwarders {
//    0.0.0.0;
// };
```

Comment: ¿Por qué debe ser con sed? ¿Qué probaste?

Comment: Debe ser con sed por que AWK es sólo para buscar información, no?

Comment: No necesariamente, awk puede hacer maravillas. Actualizo mi respuesta con una versión en ese lenguaje.

Comment: @fedorqui cuando lo intento poner en un script de bash no funciona. Mi script es este https://github.com/RafaelAybar/Bash-toolkit/blob/pruebas/servicios.sh

Comment: Ras: con `sed '...'` vemos el resultado ppr pantalla. Si quieres modificar el fichero debes usar `sed -i.bak '...'`, que modificará el fichero y creará una copia de seguridad con la extensión .bak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eliminar los `//` de principio de línea con sed solamente debes decir:

```
sed 's#^//##' fichero
```

<sub>Fíjate que uso otro delimitador para no usar `/` y tener que escapar cada una de las `/` que buscamos (y escribir algo tan feo como `sed 's/\/\///' fichero`).</sub>

Para hacer algo en unas líneas determinadas solamente debes decir:

```
sed 'linea_ini,linea_fin s/busca/sustituye/' fichero
```

Así que todo junto, lo que necesitas es:

```
sed '13,15 s#^// ##' fichero
```

Alternativamente, mi querido Awk lo hace de una forma más limpia:

```
awk 'NR>=13 && NR<=15 {sub("^//","")}1' fichero
```

Donde `NR` indica el número de la línea y `sub()` sustituye una vez (con `gsub()` lo harías múltiples veces, si se diera el caso). Finalmente, `1` se evalúa como True y, por ende, lanza un `{print $0}` que imprime la línea en evaluación. Prefiero esta versión porque permite jugar bastante con `NR` y definir distintos rangos.

---

Ejemplo:

```
$ cat fichero
// hola
// forwarders {
//    0.0.0.0;
// };
bla
```

Eliminemos `//` del principio de las líneas 2 a 4:

```
$ sed '2,4 s#^// ##' fichero
// hola
forwarders {
   0.0.0.0;
};
bla
```

Poniéndoselo algo más difícil al lenguaje para probar casos raros:

```
$ cat fichero
// hola
// forwarders { //
//    0.0.0.0;
// };
bla //
$ awk 'NR>=2 && NR<=4 {sub("^//","")}1' fichero
// hola
 forwarders { //
    0.0.0.0;
 };
bla //
```

Comment: y cómo se haría para poner una variable de bash? por que creo que las comillas simples interpretan literalmente $variable

Comment: @ras212 no me queda clara tu pregunta, pero seguramente es tan fácil como usar `sed "..."`.

Comment: `sed -i 's/0.0.0.0/$variable' ` @fedorqui

Comment: @ras212 efectivamente, con doble comilla se soluciona. `variable=23;  echo "hola 0.0.0.0 bla" | sed "s/0.0.0.0/$variable/"`

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta! Teniendo en cuenta que muchas veces un comentario puede estar tabulado, quizás convenga permitir espacios horizontales antes de las barras, y hacer que los espacios después sean opcionales (y no 1 obligatorio): `s#^[ \t]*//[ \t]*##` ... O incluso, manteniendo la tabulación original: `s#^([ \t]*)//[ \t]*#\1#`

Comment: @Mariano uau, excelente aportación. Nótese que en Sed puedes simplificar `[ \t]` con `\s`. O usar lo que POSIX define con `[:space:]` para `[ \t\r\n\v\f]` ([referencia](https://serverfault.com/a/431168/200076)).

Comment: @fedorqui es que justamente sólo deberían haber espacios o tabulaciones, y no espacios verticales. `\s` no conviene en este caso. En otros dialectos es `\h`, pero creo que no está en sed... De todas formas, releí la pregunta, y en vez de eliminar todos los espacios después, sería sólo el primero, opcional: `s#\([ \t]\*\)// \?#\1#` (o con `-r` para evitar tanta barra)

Comment: @Mariano creo que me expliqué mal: `\s` es exactamente espacios y tabulaciones.

Comment: @Mariano bien observado. Investigando, observo que `\s` es una extensión de GNU sed ([referencia](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions)): _Matches whitespace characters (spaces and tabs). Newlines embedded in the pattern/hold spaces will also match_. Otros no reconocen pues el estándar sed espera BREs ([referencia](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63881/40596)).

Comment: Gracias por la referencia! Y sí es el eterno problema de referirse a *spaces* sin aclarar la ambigüedad :-(. Y viendo los temas de compatibilidad, creo que no conviene usar nunca `\s` ni ningún otro [shorthand](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) a menos que sea solamente para una única implementación de sed que los soporte.